# How to remove OpenMP from GraphicsMagick on Windows server

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, gm

I am using **GraphicsMagick 1.3.26** on server.

Due, to performance impact. I want to remove OpenMP feature from it.

Kindly provide me the steps to remove the same for windows machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No. I have tried -limit threads 1. But, It is still taking same time to process.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried on Windows, and unable to test, but apparently you can either:

- add `-limit threads 1` to each command, or
- rebuild with `--disable-openmp` and reinstall, or
- set environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to 1 before running

[Reference](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/OpenMP.html)

---

Use:

```
gm identify -version
```

to see how your instance was built.